# How do I return a value out of a javascript some loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, return

I'm iterating over an array with a some loop to see if a time is in the past but I also want to return how many times the loop has run, how do I do that?

```
arr.some(function(a, i){
            var date = Date.parse(a.start);
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            console.log(i);
            return now-date < 0;
        });
```

Edit: Solved this by just doing a for loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return multiple objects in javascript. However, you can return a list of objects.

```
return [now-date < 0, i]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I think because the array is truthy no matter what? Edit: by doesn't work I mean it doesn't run through until now-date is negative, it just returns one value.

Comment: right, he'd have to put an if check in before he returns but this is how he could return multiple objects

Comment: if I make result equal to the function return it still just equals 'true' even after an if statement, is there ae better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Count = 0;

```
arr.some(function(a, i){
        Count = +Count + 1;
        var date = Date.parse(a.start);
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(i);
        return now-date < 0;
    });
```

You could be able to make a counter, something like this.. basicly set count to 0 first and everytime the loop runs, count = old count + 1.

Comment: the i is a variable representing the index in the list